# Extracting variables from string, regular expression?

Tags: regex, string, variables, screen-scraping, preg-match

My puzzle: as a PHP newby I am trying to extract some data from a string using a regular expression, but I cannot find a correct syntax.

The content of the string is scraped as html of several images from a website, I want the final output to be 3 seperate variables: "$Number1", "$Number2" and "$Status".

An example of the content of the input string $html:

```
<div id="system">         
<img alt="2" height="35" src="/images/numbers/2.jpg" width="18" /><img alt="2" height="35" src="/images/numbers/2.jpg" width="18" /><img alt=".5" height="35" src="/images/numbers/point5.jpg" style="margin-left: -4px" width="26" /><img alt="system statusA" height="35" src="/images/numbers/statusA.jpg" width="37" /><img alt="2" height="35" src="/images/numbers/2.jpg" width="18" /><img alt="1" height="35" src="/images/numbers/1.jpg" width="18" /><img alt=".0" height="35" src="/images/numbers/point0.jpg" style="margin-left: -4px" width="26" />
</div>
```

The possible values which can appear in this string are:

- 0.jpg
- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 3.jpg
- 4.jpg
- 5.jpg
- 6.jpg
- 7.jpg
- 8.jpg
- 9.jpg
- point0.jpg
- point5.jpg
- statusA.jpg
- statusB.jpg
- statusC.jpg
- statusD.jpg
- statusE.jpg
- statusF.jpg

The result should be variables:

- "Number1" (XX.X) based upon the first two numbers (0-9) and .0 or .5
- "Status" (statusX) based upon the status
- "Number2" (XX.X) based upon the last two numbers (0-9) and .0 or .5

Code so far:

```
$regex = '\balt='(.*?)';
preg_match($regex,$html,$match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[0];
```

Probably I have to do this in multiple steps or use another function, who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing that you should ask yourself is: "in what format is my input data". Since in this case it is clearly a snippet of HTML, you should feed that snippet to an HTML parser, and not to a regular expression engine.

I don't know the exact function names, but your code should look like this:

```
$htmltext = '<div id="system">[...]</div>';
$htmltree = htmlparser_parse($htmltext);
$images = $htmltree->find_all('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->src;
}
```

So you need to find an HTML parser that parses a string into a tree of nodes. The nodes should have methods for finding node inside them based on CSS classes, element names or node IDs. For Python this library is called *BeautifulSoup*, for Java it is *JSoup*, and I'm sure that there is something similar for PHP.

The examples provided with [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) look promising.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly DOM : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

See [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) too

Answer (score 0):

You want just the alt's? Try this xpath example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);

foreach($xpath->query('//img/@alt') as $node){
    echo $node->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. With a | as seperator it returns: '1|3|.5|statusB|8|5|.0|'. But how can I get this value into a string? I need this to split it further into 3 strings using explode.

Comment: Solved using: foreach($xpath->query('//img/@alt') as $node){ 
$input[]=$node->nodeValue;
}